# Spring Cache not working in doFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching

Spring Cache not working if called from doFilter.

Note that Spring cache is working if NOT called from doFilter() (e.g if called from rest service)

How can I enable cache in doFilter() ? (maybe cache is not allowed in doFilter?)

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CredentialsInjectionFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(
                new ConcurrentMapCache("tenants")               
            ));
        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
        display(5);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    @Cacheable("tenants")
    public void display(int number) {
        // if cache working properly, code below will not execute after the first calling
        for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {   
               System.out.println("ramon called" +number);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you're applying @Cacheable to a method that doesn't return anything (void return type). What do you expect to happen in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

How about extending org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean, and moving the caching details into a separate service class

**CacheService**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCache;
import org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class CacheService{

        @Bean
        public CacheManager cacheManager() {
            SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
            cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(
                    new ConcurrentMapCache("tenants")               
                ));
            return cacheManager;
        }


        @Cacheable("tenants")
        public void display(int number) {
            // if cache working properly, code below will not execute after the first calling
            for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {   
                   System.out.println("ramon called" +number);
            }
        }
    }
```

**CredentialsInjectionFilter**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

@Component
public class CredentialsInjectionFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Autowired
    private CacheService cacheService;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
        cacheService.display(5);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```