# Save authenticated users to database coming from Azure AD

Tags: java, angular, azure, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am working on a simple web app for learning purposes using Angular for the frontend and Java Spring for the backend. I don't have a particular problem that I want you guys to help me out with, instead I have a question about OAuth2 authentication.

I have registered my Angular SPA in Azure AD (Authorization Code Flow + PKCE), I set up roles and everything is working okay. My question is what do I do when authenticated users ping my backend? My backend has no information about the users.

I thought of a solution to make a web filter, and every time an authenticated user pings any endpoint requiring the user to be authenticated, to check the database if the user exists (through the username), and save him if he does not exist. I'm pretty sure this will work, but I don't think this is the best solution, considering my web filter will have to read from the databases for every single HTTP request that comes in, and write to the database occasionally (if the user logs in for the first time).

I shouldn't be worried about performance issues because I'm building this strictly for learning purposes, but nevertheless I want to do this the right way. I tried googling this in multiple ways, but I guess I'm not using the right keywords to find what I'm looking for. Any opinion or advice would be much appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT: I followed this article to achieve the OAuth2 + OIDC authentication and authorization, my security config in the backend is the same: https://ordina-jworks.github.io/security/2020/08/18/Securing-Applications-Azure-AD.html

Comment: Please refer [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59520785/authenticating-with-azure-directory-and-fetch-the-valid-user-roles-from-database)

Comment: you need to authenticate against the backend as well as the frontend

Comment: With OAuth2 (Authorization Code Flow + PKCE), you should be getting an access token that needs to be sent to the backend. With your backend, you don't need to store the user information but can use another API to validate if the user token is valid or not, i.e., make a call to the userinfo_endpoint with the token to see if it is still valid.  like ```GET /oidc/userinfo HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Authorization: Bearer <access token>``` -- Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @NagarajTantri, thanks for the reply. My backend already validates token with azure AD, and I am aware of the /userinfo endpoint that I can ping to get more information about the user. However, I only need basic info like email, name and surname and that information is already in the access token itself. So my question is, is my only option to check database on every request to see if the user exists and create him if he doesn't. Having a database read action on every request that comes in seems slow...

Comment: @Aleksandar if the question is only related to checking in a database or not, I believe, the real question to understand is: - How many requests/sec do you see for your app? - How huge is your User Database? Based on this, one can answer multiple things, like whether to use a cache of users and validate the cache rather than DB and so on.

Comment: @NagarajTantri like I said in the post, this app is only for learning purposes. To make things clear, I'm not trying to authenticate the users with my database, I'm trying to save the users to the database. My app doesn't have any info about the users initially, only after they've been authenticated via Azure AD, get an access and ping my backend will my app will know something about the users (through the access token). I want to save the information about the user from the access token (name surname email).

Comment: @NagarajTantri Continued: The only mechanism I am aware of to accomplish this is query my user table with the information from the access token for every HTTP request that comes in (through a web filter) but I think it is bad for performance. Is there a different way to do this that won't require me to query the database with the information from the access token for every HTTP request that comes in. How else will I know if a given authenticated user is known (saved to the database) or a new user (first time that he accessed the app)

Comment: @Aleksandar That is where you use a Cache. What you can do is, implement a custom web filter that can listen for incoming HTTP Requests, check the valid access token, get the user details and check your cache if the user exists. If not, then create an entry into the DB and then save it into the cache. You can implement a simple `CacheService` and invoke that in the custom web filter to check if the user is available (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/27091020/308565). This cache can be prefilled from the Database table of users on start of the app.

Comment: @NagarajTantri I think this will definitely solve my problem (and it's a good solution to learn). Would you mind posting this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Aleksandar, definitely. Please check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post the discussion with clarity on the requirements. If you want to use have the following:

- Accept an Azure AD logged in user to consumer your web service
- You would want to check if the user exists in your application database with minimal network latency.

With the requirement of not always hitting your Database, one option is to use a cache.

**The ideal solution** for this cache to work is:

- Ensure the cache is checked for every HTTP Request using Web Filter
- Make sure the cache is always updated with the latest users being logged in via Azure AD

Example:

Implement a `CacheService.java`

```
package com.example.springboot;

import java.util.Collections;

import org.apache.catalina.User;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCache;
import org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CacheService {

  @Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
    cacheManager.setCaches(Collections.singletonList(new ConcurrentMapCache("users")));
    return cacheManager;
  }


  @Cacheable(cacheNames = "users")
  public User getUser(String username) {
    // Code below will not execute after the first calling for the given username. 
    // So if one username is already cached, it would not invoke for the same user again from the DB.

    // Get or Create a new user based on the Database call
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then implement a web filter like:

```
package com.example.springboot;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

@Component
public class CredentialsInjectionFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

  @Autowired
  private CacheService cacheService;

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
      FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    cacheService.getUser("my_username");

    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
  }
}
```

More on Caching with Springboot: https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring/spring-caching/